# JTable with annotation in Java

Tags: java, ajax, swing, annotations, jtable

How can I create a JTable in Java using annotation? I would like to do something like this: JTable table=new JTable(Products.class). Can I? Where Products is a class with several attributes like:id,price,productName.

Comment: I'd look more towards creating a custom TableModel from the annotations, and then using that model to create your JTable.

Comment: Thank you. I could really use some help with this.

Comment: Help with what specifically? You first need to decompose your large problem into its constituent steps, and then try to solve each step in isolation. If stuck, then come back here with a much more specific and answerable question.

Comment: Well how can I create a costum TableModel from the annotations?

Answer (score -1):

There is a good article and source code in CodeProject for this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36170/Simple-and-Powerfull-TableModel-with-Reflection

There is no such annotations comes with the Java runtime (at least for now). You can implement your own method.

Define an Annotation to mark your columns for the given object:

```
public @interface TableColumn {
    String name();
    int index();
}
```

Mark the fields you want to display in your model object with this annotation:

```
class Product {
    @TableColumn(name="Product Name", index=0)
    String productName;
    ....
}
```

Create a new TableModel class -you can inherit from DefaultTableModel- and check for the given annotation for the given object.

```
class ObjectTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private Object[] objects;
    private String[] columns;
    public ObjectTableModel(Object[] objects) {
        Field[] fields = Object.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(TableColumn.class)) {
                //Add field to the list
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //return the value from objects[rowIndex] with 
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return objects.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columns[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnClasses[columnIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well the answer would be too long, but let me include important points.